# What's the purpose of `owner_sid` field in every `object_identity` in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, acl

Spring Security Acl's model describes a field `owner_sid` in the very same `acl_object_identity` table, despite of actually still needing an ACL entry for the access to work.

What's the purpose of this field, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the time this is posted, you may already have your answer. I post mine for those that come.

So, owner_sid Defines who can make changes (add, remove, update) on Access Control Entries (ACEs) for the given object identity.

Let's say we have an object BANK_ACCOUNT with owner_sid pointing to Alice's SID. When Bob will try to add an ACE at the application, let's say "BOB has PERMISSION.CAN_TRANSFER at BANK_ACCOUNT with OBJECT_ID X", an authorization strategy will trigger and will check, based on owner_sid, whether or not the one that is trying to make a change is Alice. If not, abort the insertion.